# Calling global variable of C in Python

Tags: c, python-2.7, ctypes

I want to access the global variable of c in python. I can already use/access the functions of c in python using ctypes after making a .so file.
Here's the C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int globalVar = 2;

void add_int(int num1,int num2){
    globalVar = num1+num2;
    fprintf(globalVar, "%d\n", );
}

float add_float(float num1,float num2){
    return num1+num2;
}
```

and the Python Code:

```
from ctypes import *

adder = CDLL('/home/akshay/Desktop/ffmpeg/linking/addr.so')

adder.add_int(4,5)

var = c_int.in_dll(adder,"globalVar")
print "Sum of 4 and 5 = " + str(adder.add_int(4,5))

a = c_float(5.5)
b = c_float(4.1)

add_float = adder.add_float
add_float.restype = c_float
print "Sum of 5.5 and 4.1 = ", str(add_float(a, b))
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See [Accessing values exported from dlls](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls) from the python documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this one-line source for a Windows DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int test = 5;
```

You access global variables by using the `.in_dll()` method of a ctypes type, which takes a ctypes DLL reference and the name of the global variable:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('test')   # test.dll of the above source.
>>> c_int.in_dll(dll,'test')
c_long(5)
```

Comment: I want to use it in ubuntu. So how to implement this for .so files

Comment: @Akshay Same Python code, I just had a Windows system to test with.  Just export a global variable in a .so file.

Comment: It is showing me the error of undefined symbol.                                           
ValueError: /home/akshay/Desktop/ffmpeg/linking/addr.so: undefined symbol: globalVar

Comment: You may need something like `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` in Linux to do the equivalent of Windows' `__declspec(dllexport)` to export the definition from the shared library.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility.  I don't have a Linux account handy to work it out.

Comment: @Akshay `extern int globalVar;` may also work.  My Linux is rusty.